# Button gets longer and add text when hover

Tags: html, css

I have this whatsapp button on the bottom right of my page, i'm trying to make the button a little longer and add the text "Click here and talk with us!" when i hover the button. Can someone help me please?  I wish that the right side of the button gets straight and completely attached to the right of the page but the left side continues round.

```css
.float{
        position:fixed;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        bottom:40px;
        right:40px;
        background-color:#25d366;
        color:#FFF;
        border-radius:50px;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:40px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
        z-index:100;
    }

    .my-float{
        margin-top:16px;
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#" class="float" target="_blank">
   <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>  
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this can help

css:

```
button {
        width: 50px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid darkgreen;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        
    }
    button:hover {
        width: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    button:hover::after {
        content: ' - more text';
    }
```

html

```
<button>Text</button>
```